# Output Python dictionary in nicely formatted json for VSCode

Tags: python, json

I am trying write a function in a Jupyter Notebook that outputs a dictionary into a format that I can paste into a VSCode launch.json file and has the correct indentation. But if I use `json.dumps`, the format doesn't look good.

```
def create_dict():
    d = {}
    d["request"] = "launch"
    d["args"] = ["run", "param1=10", "param2=yes", "param3=100", "param4=0", "param5=no"]
    return json.dumps(d)
```

It comes out like this. No matter how long the string is it's just one line:

```
'{"request": "launch", "args": ["run", "param1=10", "param2=yes", "param3=100", "param4=0", "param5=no"]}'
```

I thought I could fix this by indenting it like so, but then the result is:

```
def create_dict():
    d = {}
    d["request"] = "launch"
    d["args"] = ["run", "param1=10", "param2=yes", "param3=100", "param4=0", "param5=no"]
    return json.dumps(d, indent=4)

'{\n    "request": "launch",\n    "args": [\n        "run",\n        "param1=10",\n        "param2=yes",\n        "param3=100",\n        "param4=0",\n        "param5=no"\n    ]\n}'
```

Which isn't what I want at all. The format I'm looking for is exactly what I get from return just the dictionary, but I need double-quotes to be json compatible.

```
def create_dict():
    d = {}
    d["request"] = "launch"
    d["args"] = ["run", "param1=10", "param2=yes", "param3=100", "param4=0", "param5=no"]
    return d

{'request': 'launch',
 'args': ['run',
  'param1=10',
  'param2=yes',
  'param3=100',
  'param4=0',
  'param5=no']}
```

This is exactly the format I want, how do I preserve it and get double quotes?

Comment: Check out [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) for specifying formatting options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was to wrap the json in a `print` statement:

```
def create_dict():
    d = {}
    d["request"] = "launch"
    d["args"] = ["run", "param1=10", "param2=yes", "param3=100", "param4=0", "param5=no"]
    return print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))


create_dict()

{
    "request": "launch",
    "args": [
        "run",
        "param1=10",
        "param2=yes",
        "param3=100",
        "param4=0",
        "param5=no"
    ]
}
```